# Does this count as Tzedakah?

Tags: technology, mitzvah, tzedakah-charity

I found out there's an app that gives money to charity depending on how much you run. You can choose between dozens of organizations that help stop hunger, help the homeless, cure cancer, provide vaccines to poor people, build schools, etc. I found this completely awesome and I'm totally going to use it; however, I don't know if this counts as Tzedakah because it's not me who's actually paying this, not even a cent comes from my pocket.

*If you'd like to download it, it's called Charity Miles.*

Comment: I would say that your supposition is probably correct, but it might be like volunteering your time at a soup kitchen. On the other hand, if you were going to run anyways, the situation might be different.

Comment: @sabbahillel Then what mitzvah would be volunteering my time for needed people?

Comment: It might be considered as having "paid" the worth of your time to tzedakah. The phrase as I recall is *schar bitul melacha*, (payment for not performing paying work). This is similar to donating an item that you had purchased to tzedakah. In the *Charity Miles* case,  monetary tzedakah comes from the donor and you might be credited with having provided the excuse for the donation (since you would have been running those miles in any event).

Comment: @sabbahillel I think there may be various nuances to the term *tzedaka* that extend beyond money. I have to explore that notion. Until then, it sounds like volunteering time in a soup kitchen is called *chessed*.

Comment: Sounds alike a review of the [laws of Tzedaka](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_36.html) are in order:.

Comment: Count as tzedaka in what regard?

Comment: If by saying 'tzedakah', you mean giving money to charity, strictly speaking the answer would be no. Your action would fall under the definition of 'Gemilut Chesed', and Act of Kindness. Unlike giving money to charity, there is no limit to the acts of kindness one may perform and it is also a mitzvah. In addition, you also fulfill the mitzvah of maintaining good physical health which is another way to serve HaShem. Rambam says it is impossible to learn or pray properly without good physical health.

Comment: @YaacovDeane is your comment from svarah, or do you have a source?

Comment: yo''d 149:5 says that if you cause someone to give tzedaka, you get more schar than the person who gave it (אִם יָכוֹל לַעֲשׂוֹת לַאֲחֵרִים שֶׁיִּתְּנוּ, שְׂכָרוֹ גָּדוֹל מִשְּׂכַר הַנּוֹתֵן). I wonder if that applies here.

Comment: @RibisShmibis No, it isn't by reason. It is the halacha and is simply understanding the meaning of the words. 'Acts of kindness', meaning Gemilut Chesed, which have no upper limit. In the context of the question, the running is what causes the sponsors to pay cash. The giving of cash is tzedakah, which has a limit per individual. The running is an act of kindness. And as I mentioned, there is also a mitzvah to be physically healthy.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I agree with you in svara, but how do you know that causing someone to give tzedaka doesn't count as tzedaka? Yo''d 149:5 says that if you cause someone to give tzedaka, you get more schar than the person who gave it. Perhaps this schar is for gamilus chasadim, or perhaps this schar is for tzedaka. We see the concept of causing someone to give tzedaka, I was just wondering if you had a written source saying that tzedaka has to be with money. In yo''d 249 there are ways of giving tzedaka mentioned that aren't money. (all are"giving" but perhaps it opens the door to other methods)

Comment: (perhaps the "giving" of time could count)

Comment: @RibisShmibis See Avot 2:2, 5:13 & 5:18 in regard to your question on Yorah Deah 149:5.

Answer (score -1):

if it goes to a halachikly acceptable cause it will count as if you gave it, the same one can make a monetary acquisition or be mikadash a women by causing someone else to give. it also works for maser. see kidushin 7a

Comment: Why? How do you know?

Comment: Define _halachikly acceptable_!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21490)

Comment: @andrewmh20, he said how he knows: "the same [as] one can make a monetary acquisition or be mikadash a women by causing someone else to give".

Comment: This post would be a great deal more valuable if you would [edit] it to make your arguments clearer and to found them directly in relevant sources.

Comment: Sorry i can not define halachikly  acceptable, i don't know. (and it probably  will depend who ask) i only intend to answer the question in regard to using miles for tzdaka

Comment: @DannySchoemann - He most likely means a decent charitable cause. "Halachically acceptable" was not a good choice of words. :)